# Can not open Mozilla firefox browser on windows 7

Tags: firefox

While clicking on firefox icon, many times can not open on window 7, is there any 
option to start firefox,  firefox version is 54.0

installed location path.
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox

System Config.
Windows 7 Home Basic
Service pack 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was in my system, .dll file was corrupted related to related to Firefox browser, therefore windows 7 was not responding to "Mozilla Firefox" browser.